# How to obtain the computer's hard drive serial number, BIOS ID, CPU number, MAC and so on use Mathematica?

Tags: system-variables, hardware, commercial-package

I want to packed my program use RSA algorithm.  Of course, `$MachineID` can be used but I want to make it safer. Can *Mathematica* obtain the computer's hard drive serial number, BIOS ID, CPU number, MAC and so on?  Or any other Machine Key?  The command `SystemInformation[]` seems not include the other Machine Key.

Comment: What OS are you on?  Cross OS I'm quiet certain there is no way.

Comment: All of my user's OS is Windows Thank you very much!

Comment: The Mac address was a little tricky

Comment: If already using `wmic`, then simply `wmic nic get MacAddress` should list all the MAC addresses.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to Oleksandr R. wmic can only be run by Administrators.
Here is how you get the Serial on Windows.

```
Import["!wmic bios get serialnumber", "Text"]
```

To get CPU information

```
Import["!wmic cpu get NumberOfCores, NumberOfLogicalProcessors/Format:List", "Text"]
```

To get the MAC Address run.

```
StringSplit[
  StringReplace[
   StringCases[Import["!ipconfig /all", "Text"], 
    "Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :" ~~ x___], 
   "Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : " -> ""], "\n"][[1, 1]]
```

And to get BIOS ID.

```
Import["!wmic bios get name,serialnumber,version", "Text"]
```

Comment: I upvoted, but it should be mentioned that `wmic` can only be run by administrators. This is likely to be a problem in general, although I can't see any way around it.

Comment: Also, you only get the first MAC address from `ipconfig`, and it is not guaranteed that all media types have the same length of physical address. For instance on my computer I have 4, 6, and 8-byte physical addresses.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I admit I was concerned my mac address approach wasn't very practical.

Comment: Instead of `ipconfig /all` you could also use `getmac` which is more compact.

Answer (score 6):

The only thing I could find very easily is the *HWaddr* of the network device that can be obtained by

```
SystemInformation["Network", "IPAddresses"]
```

Comment: One can get the same output with [`$MachineAddresses`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MachineAddresses.html).